# Is there an online archive of the art for every draft booster pack ever printed?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm looking for an archive of high quality photos or scans of all artwork ever printed on a draft booster pack.

For example, the Mirage set had five (or more?) different booster packs printed.

[image: This image isn't great, but with editing each pack could be rotated slightly and be usable for what I want.]

Recent sets are fairly easy to find with a search engine but finding out how many variations old sets had can difficult. Finding decent images for these older sets can also be very time consuming.

Does such an archive exist online?

Answer (score 2):

While there doesn't appear to be an online gallery, and Wizards may have something to say about one they didn't generate, someone did compile a file of the artwork up to 2013.  This may provide the help with the older sets you were lamenting.  https://www.slightlymagic.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=9825